# Install or print report without Visual studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

My windows forms Pos application was made in Vs 2010, with `CRforVs_13.0.exe`  installed to print the report.

When I have install to my client's machine, even with the same `CRforVs_13.0.exe` , its says we need to install Visual Studio.

How can my client print the Crystal Report without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

`CRforVs_13.0.exe` literally means "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio". You must install the [Crystal Reports runtime redistributable](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads).

Look for the appropriate MSI file on that table. Be aware if you need [32bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20.zip) or [64bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20.zip).

The `.exe` is for Visual Studio integration while the `.msi` is for run time.

Comment: can you provide the link for Crystal Reports runtime redistributable because i am not able to find it in https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads, there are four fixed issues pack sp17-sp20 release it will support vs 2010 32 and 64 bit machine?